# JavaCC: Multiple equal characters in token definition

Tags: java, regex, token, lexer, javacc

in JavaCC how can I define a token consisting of repeating characters such as exemplified below:

> "..."
>   what would correspond to

```
TOKEN : { TripleDot : "..." }
```

or

> "::"
>   what would correspond to

```
TOKEN : { DoubleColon : "::" }
```

or

> "//"
>   what would correspond to

```
TOKEN : { DoubleSlash : "//" }
```

etc.

The JavaCC compiler lets me define these tokens without warning message but as soon I use these tokens within another lexical token rule wherein this definition is one alternative I am getting a warning. See below:

Given the rules above when I write

```
TOKEN : { TestToken : <DoubleColon> }
```

I am getting no warning. But when I write

```
TOKEN : { TestToken : "test" | <DoubleColon> }
```

the JavaCC compiler tells me the following:

> Waning: Line 84: Column 9: Regular Expression Choice: TestToken can
>   never be matched as: DoubleColon.

But why is this? I understand that it might be difficult for the Lexer to recognize repeating characters but then I should be able to define a LOOKAHEAD even in the token definitions which I can't.

What do I miss?

**ADDENDUM:**

I event tried this out:

```
TOKEN : { DoubleSlash : "/"{2} }
```

without any success. It has the same effect.

Comment: If you want to match repeating characters, you need to add parentheses and append a `+` quantifier: `TOKEN : { < DoubleColon : ("::")+ > }`

Comment: Yes, but that only gives me the well known EBNF options "zero or more" (with kleene star) or "one or more" (with kleene plus). I want to have e.g. exactly 2 dots such as `..`. And in your case it will even give me multiples of two colons.

Answer (score 1):

I did found a solution for my problem which is simpler than expected:

In order to define tokens consisting of multiple equal characters one might only need to define one instance of this particular character

e.g.

```
TOKEN : { < Slash : "/" > }
```

in order to then do the following:

```
TOKEN : { < TrippleSlash : <Slash><Slash><Slash> > }
```

I already coded and tested it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: It's simpler than that. You can have `TOKEN:{ <TRIPPLESLASH : "///" > }` or `TOKEN:{ <HEPTADECASLASH: ("/"){17} > }`.

Answer (score 0):

You need are "private regular expressions".  See [The JavaCC documentation](https://javacc.java.net/doc/javaccgrm.html#prod19)

```
If the label is preceded by a "#", then this regular expression may
not be referred to from expansion units, but only from within other regular
expressions. When the "#" is present, the regular expression is referred
to as a "private regular expression".
```

Thus, you can do the following

```
TOKEN : { #DoubleColon : "::" }
TOKEN : { TestToken : "test" | <DoubleColon> }
```

And there will be no warning.

Of course you can not use `<DoubleColon>` in any grammar productions, as it is private.

---

If you are under the delusion that you should be able to have productions

```
TOKEN : { DoubleColon : "::" }
TOKEN : { TestToken : "test" | <DoubleColon> }
```

in hopes that "::" is sometimes a `<DoubleColon>` and sometimes a `<TestToken>`, then you need to consult  [FAQ 3.3](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc3.3) and [FAQ 3.6](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc3.6).